# How to I compute a string written as an expression?

Tags: java

An input of string is passed as an argument to a comptute function.The string can contain up to three
values of numbers and some operators like * - / +? For example, "25.7-14*34" is valid

This is the format:

```
public double compute(String input){
    ...
}
```

I think I would need a condition to check if a character is an operator but I don't know how to check for it in Java. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Character` class in case you are planning to do it yourself.

`Character.isLetterOrDigit()`, `Character.getType(c) == Character.MATH_SYMBOL` to check whether the character passed `c` is a math symbol or not. 
There are a lot of other static methods present in `Character` class which you can make use of.